# Java, IMAP, check if message has attachment without fetching

Tags: java, email, imap, message, attachment

I have a large mailbox of millions of messages. I want only to learn for each messge, whether it has an attachment or not. (Not interested size, name, count of attachments, only true false is enough). When i use this code and monitor with a profiler tool, I see that the message.getContent() consumes memory and does not clear it.  Because dealing with millions of messages, out of memory issues occur. The reason is, the getContent() methot caches some data and keeps it.

What is an alternative to this code without calling *getContent*?
Or how can i force to clear the cache  which is set by getContent?
How can I apply *message.writeTo()* for this case?

```
//processing million message instances in a loop i=1, 1000000

Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message[i].getContent();
for (int i = 0; i < multiPart.getCount(); i++) {
    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
        // yes, it has an attachment
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Maybe you can reduce messages by seen or unseen messages. Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988799/javamail-check-message-content-gmail-imap

Comment: I need all of them because of some business rules. I fetch only headers (subject, from etc) and ignore body, attachments without any memory or performance problem. But I only need if has attachment or not. Fetching body and attachments are done when user selects any message later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic java problem. The general pattern is

```
while(true) {
    Something foo = new Something();
    processSomehow(foo);
    someCollection.add(foo);
}
// at this point, all of the created objects remain reachable
```

Each foo is not used after it leaves the loop, but they all remain reachable, so the JVM grows very large. The classic solution is not not retain references to things you will not need. In your case the `message` array keeps this reachable.

Comment: My message array is not 1 million messages long. I handle them in 1000 blocks and fetch 1000 messages, process, empty the array and continue with next. When no call of getContent is done, no memory problems occur.

Comment: The IMAPFolder is/has such an array, so you do have one unless you close and reopen the folder. Reopening a big folder is is very slow, though. You can make each message smaller by calling [invalidateHeaders()](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.html#invalidateHeaders--), which deletes much more than its documentation says. Maybe doing that and reopening every 50k messages or so is enough.

Comment: Thank you, i have done this today already, and the memory is released after each close, the problems seems solved with getContent. On the other hand, I tried sending customprotocol command with UID FETCH and BODYSTRUCTURE, the memory usage is very small compared to getContent, there is no need to open/close folder. Both methods seem to work.